# hikaricp get number of busy connection

Tags: jdbc, connection, c3p0, pooling, hikaricp

Like we can get the number of busy connection in c3p0 by using method like `dataSource.getNumBusyConnections()`, the same way how can we do that in case of hikaricp? Can anyone provide all the related methods between c3p0 and hikaricp? Also what is the destroy (in c3p0) method equivalent in hikaricp?

Comment: There seem to be too many questions here. _Can anyone provide all the related methods between c3p0 and hikaricp_ seems to me too broad too.

Answer (score 0):

Re: connections, see these wiki pages:

[JMX Monitoring (via console and programatically](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JMX-Monitoring)

[Using Codahale/Dropwizard Metrics](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Codahale-Metrics)

`HikariDataSource` supports both `close()` and `shutdown()` methods, they are equivalent.

UPDATE: I put out a [simple gist](https://gist.github.com/brettwooldridge/405d7c54784fc3a99813) that uses JMX you can try.