# difference between HikariPool and HikariDatasource

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, c3p0, pooling, hikaricp

When we use c3p0 we dnt have to use any pool,but when it comes to hikaricp to find out the number of active and idle we have to get the pool first.Can anyone show how to put that in example

Comment: See answer to your [previous question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268286/hikaricp-get-number-of-busy-connection